# Why is mysqli num rows not returning anything?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have some code which is supposed to verify the username and password for a login (Don't yell at me, I already sanitize the strings earlier in the code using GUMP):

```
$verif_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = \"".$_POST['user']."\" AND password = \"".hash("sha512",$_POST['passwd'].mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($DB,"SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = \"".$_POST['user']."\"")))."\"";
$userpass_verif = mysqli_query($DB,$verif_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($userpass_verif) <= 0){
  die("Invalid un/pass");
}
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention, I echoed out $verif_query and ran it against phpmyadmin, and it returned 1 row. Sorry, my question was not comprehensive.

UPDATE2: I messed the code example up while typing the question. I did verify the DB connection and I did include the $DB in the query. Again, sorry for the bad question.

Comment: You didn't check if your query succeeded. If it failed for some reason, `mysqli_error` would tell you why. Since there's no such check, you are in the dark.

Comment: you dont verify the connection database prior to your query

Comment: Eww, that is some nasty SQL injection risk you got there. Escape user input before passing it to DB. `<input type='text' name='user' value='"; DROP DATABASE users;'>` ;)

Comment: @DeDee Not working with `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @Gumbo could you elaborate in one or two sentences? Can't execute multiple statements in a single query using `mysqli` or can't pass unescaped input? `mysqli::real_escape_string` must exist for a reason.

Comment: @DeDee `mysqli::query` does only execute one single statement.

Comment: @DeDee I already did the string sanitization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc(
    mysqli_query(
        "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE "
        . "username = \"" . $_POST['user'] . "\""
    )
)
```

You are actually getting an associative array, not the user's salt as a string. If the user's salt was 'the-salt', this is what you will get:

```
Array
(
    [salt] => the-salt
)
```

When concatenating the users password (e.g. 'the-password') and that array, you will get:

```
the-passwordArray
```

As the password hash used for verification will be made out of that string, the query will (most probably) not match anything and you won't get any rows returned from the verification query.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used the implode function to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

use this before die() and tell us the error you got

```
echo mysqli_errno($this->db_link);
```